# Where can I find documentation of older version of jQuery libraries?

Tags: jquery

Where can I find documentation of older version of jQuery libraries?

For example: jQuery 1.2.7

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here you can find documentation for all versions:

http://charupload.wordpress.com/2007/12/07/jquery-documentation-chm/

In your case:

http://go2.wordpress.com/?id=725X1342&site=charupload.wordpress.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fchar-docs.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FjQuery%2520and%2520jQuery%2520UI%2520Reference%25201.2.chm&sref=http%3A%2F%2Fcharupload.wordpress.com%2F2007%2F12%2F07%2Fjquery-documentation-chm%2F

Comment: The second link is broken.

Comment: Though the site in question looks extremely sketchy, the download seems good. (I'm tasked with writing a page for McDonald's Canada, whose site is stuck on Jquery 1.3.2 -- ouch.)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty old question but maybe my answer would be helpful for someone.

To get API for prior versions of jQuery you can use *The Wayback Machine*:

https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://api.jquery.com/

To select a date you need you can find a JQuery release date [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history).